# I cant figure out how to make my article h1 post title and line height resposnive on small screens like when viewing site from phone

Tags: css, wordpress

I cant figure out how to make this work. I have been trying different things with no luck. I just want to increase the posts entry h1 font size and line height. This issue is, that every time I attempt this change and then check my phone, the font size and line height stay huge and nonresposnive. I have to do this through css since my theme has no theme options to increase the post title h1. Right now it is responsive but if I attempt any changes then the main post h1 title looses all responsiveness.

This is one of the attempts that had no luck because even though this css worked, I had to remove it because, it striped the h1 post title from adjusting when the post is viewed on a smaller screen ... the font size and line height stayed huge:

```
.post-cover-title .post-title {
font size: 3.25em;
line-height: 62px;
}
```

Here is the [link](http://iamdentistry.com/archive/dentistry/dentist-suicide-rate/) to a post where you can check it out on firebug.

Thank you for any help, I appreciate it.

I asked this same question somewhere else but they did not understand my issue so here was my copy/paste response:

the problem is that when I set the font size to a different font size for the header. Then it is not responsive anymore. Right now the theme defaults to a 50px header font size. I want to make it a 52px header font size. But when I do make it 52px through CSS, and then check it on my phone then I notice that the new 52px font size is no longer adjusting to the new smaller screen size but rather stays too large… vs the defaults 50 px font size that is the default of the theme, which adjust perfectly to a new screen size. So somehow by me targeting it though css it looses all responsiveness for smaller screen sizes.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){
    .post-cover-title .post-title {
        font-size: 35px!important;
        line-height: 35px!important;
    }
}
```

(Change to the font-size and line height you want)